# How to make Gatsby load some scripts after UI rendering?

Tags: javascript, gatsby

There are some external script for playing video on my site that I am building using Gatsby. But the problem is this script slowing the performance of the site.

So, I want this script to load only after rendering of complete page. I mean this script is not involved in initial build process.

How can I do this? Where should I load this code?

If needed, I am ready to provide further information.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out lazy loading with `React.lazy()`. This might be what you want.

Comment: Gatsby is based on React, so you're actually creating React components in your page.  You should look at the React docs about component lifecycle, esp componentDidMount which only fires after the component is initally rendered.  See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount